# Expecting variable in READ statement at (1)

Tags: fortran

I wrote a file with x extension. Now I would like to read it, but when I try to compile I get the error "Expecting variable in Read statement at (1)"

This is how I wrote the x file:

```
          program avewmean

      REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION (:) :: yc,zc
      INTEGER :: p1,p2,p3
      ny=192
      nz=192

      ALLOCATE(yc(ny+1))
      ALLOCATE(zc(nz+1))

      open(11,file='wmean2d.x',form='unformatted')
      write  (11) p3,p2
      write  (11) (((zc(k)),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny),
     .            (((yc(j)),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny)
      close(11)

      stop
      end
```

and this is how I am trying to read it:

```
          program avewmean

      REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION (:) :: yc,zc
      INTEGER :: p1,p2,p3
      ny=192
      nz=192

      ALLOCATE(yc(ny+1))
      ALLOCATE(zc(nz+1))

      open(11,file='wmean2d.x',form='unformatted')
      read  (11) p3,p2
      read  (11) (((zc(k)),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny),
     .            (((yc(j)),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny)
      close(11)

      stop
      end
```

The compilation command is:

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -o avwmean2d2 avwmean2d2.f
```

The error that I get is referring to the line "`read  (11) (((zc(k)),k=1,nz)`":

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Since I wrote the code in that way, I thought I could read it just by substituting "write" with "read". This is not even the first time I try something like this.

Comment: In addition to what @VladimirFГероямслава commented, also give us the complete error message, for example it should have shown you where the error exists.

Comment: Have you allocated the arrays before reading into them? Where is (1) referring to in the error message?

Comment: Yes, they really start at column 7

Answer (score 5):

It is a typo-like error, but I think it deserves a closer explanation in an answer. Curiously, Intel Fortran compiles the code without complaning, which made the debugging even harder.

It is easy to get lost in the parentheses due to the double implied do loop, but the same error would also happen with

```
      read  (11) (p3),(p2)
```

The items of the input list, `(p3)` and `(p2)` are expressions, not variables. This is because of the parentheses around the variables. Therefore, gfortran refuses to compile the code because variables are required in the input list. In a similar way you cannot read `p2+p3` you cannot also read `(p3)` or `(p2)`.

Similarly, you need

```
      read  (11) ((zc(k),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny),
     .            ((yc(j),k=1,nz),
     .                      j=1,ny)
```

Comment: Perhaps the _op_ was a LISP programmer before  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem!!